# TTFB with xhr request extensive long waiting time

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, cloudflare, blueimp

The issue I run into is that when I upload files I chunk them into smaller pieces. After each chunk a new request gets sent. These requests have a long TTFB waiting time as you can see here:

[image: screenshot]

It takes 1.2 mins to upload 50mb and then 30 seconds to respond from Cloudflare to my server in order to start the next 50mb chunk.

Is there a way I can disable Cloudflare for http://testnow.ga/jquery-file-upload only and not for http://testnow.ga/ ?